# Sampling with rejections

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a probability measure $P$ on $\mathcal X$ and a measurable mapping $f\colon \mathcal X\to \{0, 1\}$ such that $P(f^{-1}(1)) > 0$.

Consider the following sampling procedure:

1. Sample a point $x\sim P$.
2. If $f(x)=1$, return $x$. Else, go to 1.

As $f^{-1}(1)$ has positive measure, the above procedure almost surely returns some sample $y$.

To phrase it in the language of random variables, if $X_1, X_2, \dotsc$ is an infinite sequence of i.i.d. random variables distributed according to $P$, then the resulting variable $Y$ can be defined as $Y(\omega) = X_i(\omega)$, where $i$ is the smallest index (again, almost surely it will exist) such that $f(X_i(\omega)) = 1$.

I wonder how the resulting distribution of $Y$ will look like.
I suspect something like conditional probability $P(x\mid f(x)=1)$, but I do not know how to prove that.

Any hints or references to literature studying such distributions would be very welcome. I suspect that there is a connection between this problem and rejection sampling and Markov chain Monte Carlo methods, but I don't really see it.

Comment: I think your intuition is correct, using Markov property you can prove the equivalence of your sample generating procedure to this one: 

*Continuously generate $n$ iid $x_{i}\sim P$, then collect all those $x_{i}$ with $f(x_{i})=1$*. 

The empirical distribution of the latter one is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{x_{i}\in E}1_{f(x_{i})=1}/\bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{f(x_{i})=1}\bigr)$ which is $n/\bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{f(x_{i})=1}\bigr)\times 1/n\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{x_{i}\in E}1_{f(x_{i})=1}$ converging to $1/P(f(X)=1)\times P(X\in E\cap f^{-1})=P(X\in E|f(X)=1)$ by GC theorem.

Comment: Thank you! This is an interesting perspective, but I don't see why (formally) this continuous case is equivalent to the discrete sampling procedure. (Probably I'm missing some of the required background in probability!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N$ be the random variable defined by $N(\omega)=\inf\{k\geqslant 1, f(X_k(\omega))=1\}$ and let $p=\mathbb P(f^{-1}(1))$. We want the distribution of $X_N$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_N\in  B)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb P(X_n\in B, N=n)&\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb P\left(\{X_n\in B\}\cap \{f(X_n)=1\}\cap \bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}\{f(X_i)\neq 1\}\right)&\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb P\left(\{X_n\in B\}\cap \{f(X_n)=1\}\right)(1-p)^{n-1}& \mbox{ by independence} \\
&= P(B\cap f^{-1}(1))\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}\\
&=P(B\cap f^{-1}(1))/p\\
&=P\left(B\mid f^{-1}(1)\right).
\end{align}